# Tensorflow session run() hangs even if queue runner has been started, why?

Tags: tensorflow

My program tries to read tfrecords file from disk. I use the queue APIs of tensorflow, But it hangs at the line session run, I do not know why, I have started the queue runners. and my program is as follows:

```
batch_size = 512
def decode_tfr(filename, train=True):
    if type(filename) != list:
        filename = [filename]
    shuffle = True if train else False
    capacity = 16 if train else 1
    num_epochs = None if train else 1
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename, shuffle=shuffle,
                                                num_epochs=num_epochs,
                                                capacity=capacity)
    if train:
        examples_queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(
        capacity=batch_size * 8,
        min_after_dequeue=batch_size * 2,
        dtypes=[tf.string])
    else:
        examples_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(
        capacity=batch_size * 8,
        dtypes=[tf.string])

    enqueue_ops = []
    num_readers=1
    for _ in range(num_readers):
        reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
        _, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
        enqueue_ops.append(examples_queue.enqueue([value]))

    tf.train.queue_runner.add_queue_runner(
    tf.train.queue_runner.QueueRunner(examples_queue, enqueue_ops))
    example_serialized = examples_queue.dequeue()

    num_preprocess_threads = 10
    items = []
    for thread_id in range(num_preprocess_threads):
        record = parse_example_proto(example_serialized)
        items.append(list(record))

    record = tf.train.batch_join(
        items,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        dynamic_pad=True,
        capacity=2 * num_preprocess_threads * batch_size)
    return record
```

Then in the main block, my code is like this:

```
filename = './test.tfr'

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    items = decode_tfr(filename)

config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord, start=True)
print("start...")
try:
    while not coord.should_stop():
        for i in xrange(1):
            print("before run...")
            print(items[0])
            a = sess.run(items[0])
            print("after run...")
        break
except Exception:
    print("Done!")

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
quit()
```

When I run the program, it hangs at the line: `sess.run()`
I do not understand why it hangs?
Because I have started the `queue_runners` as said on the tensorflow website.
Thanks very much.

I use `top` command and find the cpu utility of this process is above 300%.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find it out myself.
the `test.tfr` file is empty, so the `sess.run()` hangs forever!